# Azure getting metrics "Authentication failed" issue

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm creating a PowerShell script to get metrics from Azure. I have an app registration with API permission to Insights-UserMetric.Read.All (application type).
Also Monitoring Reader role assigned to this app at subscription level.
When running a script I'm getting error:

```
{   "error": {     "code": "AuthenticationFailed",     "message": "Authentication failed."   } }
```

I tried to raise role to Contributor just to check if I don't have sufficient permissions, but even with Contributor role I'm getting same error

Here is the script:

```
$ClientId = 'someClientId'
$ClientSecret = 'someClientSecret'
$Tenantid = 'someTenantId'

$TokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type = "client_credentials"
    Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    Client_Id = $ClientId
    Client_Secret = $ClientSecret
}
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$Tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $TokenBody

$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($tokenResponse.access_token)"
    "Content-type" = "application/json"
}

$Uri = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/$eventHub/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01'

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $Uri -Method GET
```

Appreciate any kind of guidance

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Token part fixed:

```
$TokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type = "client_credentials"
    Scope = "https://management.azure.com/.default"
    Client_Id = $ClientId
    Client_Secret = $ClientSecret
    Tenant_Id = $TenantId
}
```

Comment: That scope declaration is a bit strange, never seen that in my 8 years of working with Azure. I wouldn't use that in a script either. Also don't use the application registration secrets directly in your script but store them in a key vault and reference the key vault script in your ticket.